# How to know when a collection view outline has been expanded?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, diffabledatasource

I am using an outline view style `UICollectionView` setup and setting up my header cells like so:

```
var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
content.text = brand.name ?? "Unknown"
cell.contentConfiguration = content
  
let headerDisclosureOption = UICellAccessory.OutlineDisclosureOptions(style: .header)
cell.accessories = [.outlineDisclosure(options: headerDisclosureOption)]
```

However is it possible to receive something like a delegate call whenever a cell section is expanded? I would like to pull fresh data from the internet whenever a list is expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the diffable data source's `sectionSnapshotHandlers` property. It is a SectionSnapshotHandlers instance, a struct consisting entirely of properties whose values are functions. Those functions, which you assign, are your callbacks.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/3600966-sectionsnapshothandlers

Comment: Excuse my lack of proper comment etiquette, I'll only say this one. I want to personally thank you Matt, you've answered my questions from the start of my iOS development journey to today and am a better developer because of it, thanks and happy holidays :-)

Comment: Thanks, I got that answer straight from my own book. Just saying!

Comment: @matt is there any way to detect when this expand/collapse has been finished? I need to update my view size based on the size of the collection. My "dirty" trick for now is to use willExpandItem/willCollapseItem and inside wait for a little bit and then check for the collectionView size. It works bit I wish there was a didExpandItem or similar

Comment: @Godfather So layoutSubviews doesn't capture it?

Comment: @matt `layoutSubviews` from the view itself (a UICollectionView) it does actually notice those changes. But this `collectionView` is hosted by a `UIViewController` and there I'm unable to capture those changes (just tried on `viewDidLayoutSubviews`). So after clikcing any section expand or collapse this method does not get triggered. Should I pass a callback to my child view (the collectionView) in order to do so? In the parent VC is where I resize the VC accordingly.

Comment: What I had to do but seems super hacky still for me: from the child view I pass a callback when I create it. This callback will get executed in `willExpandItem` and `willCollapseItem`. On the parent I receveive it, and then I do the trick of waiting 0.1 and then check the size of the `scrollView.contentSize.height`

Comment: I'm not grasping your view controller architecture, and the comments on my answer are not a fit venue for discussion. Please open a new question in which you provide the necessary info.